# What is the purpose/meaning of the Version property on a FormsAuthenticationTicket?

Tags: asp.net, security, forms-authentication

What is the purpose/meaning of the Version property on a FormsAuthenticationTicket?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just storing the ticket version number, you can understand the structure of the ticket by this value. It stores 1 for asp.net 1.1 and 2 for asp.net 2.0. Maybe in the future Microsoft will add some extra fields to the ticket then the version number will be 3.0. This number can be used by another software to differentiate tickets.

Answer (score 2):

The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.version.aspx) are less than enlightening on this one, though the default version number did change [from 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.version(VS.71).aspx) to 2 with ASP.NET 2.0.

Reflector didn't turn up any interesting uses of it either, other than keeping it alive on renews. My guess is that it's for "future use".